# From AS2 to AS3 what is the equvalent of _root?

Tags: actionscript-3, migration, actionscript-2

I'm trying to learn Actionscript 2 or 3, with AS2 I eventually figured by trial and error that I could get any named instance and modify it using a string with its name using

```
var theinstance = "titletext"; // actually exctracted from an array
_root[theinstance].htmlText = "New text with <b>HTML!</b>";
```

but when trying to convert the code to AS3 `_root` doesn't exist anymore. According to the [migration doc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/migration.html) it is somehow replaced by `flash.display.DisplayObject.stage` but apparently this is not how to do it:

```
flash.display.DisplayObject.stage[theinstance].htmlText = "New text with <b>HTML!</b>";
```

and neither is this:

```
flash.display.DisplayObject.stage.getChildByName(theinstance).htmlText = "New text with <b>HTML!</b>";
```

How *do* I get a child by name in actionscript 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use either "root" (no underscore) or "stage" depending on exactly what you want to do.

However - Why not just store a reference to the textField in the array instead of a string?

Comment: I want to use string values to search for the name using a string (more often than i want to address a textarea), probably better ways to do it, though.

Comment: I tried your idea, it works fine when I just added `.name` in the search function.

Comment: The getChildByName function is not for adding assets from the library, it's for accessing children of a DisplayObjectContainer by name. (You may be thinking of flash.utils.getDefinitionByName())

Answer (score 2):

"flash.display.DisplayObject" is not literally part of the actual code that you call.  Rather, the documentation is telling you that the stage property is available on any *instance of the DisplayObject class* -- for example, a movieClip or a sprite.

For example, if you have a movieClip named foo, you could reference the stage with:

```
foo.stage
```

and go from there.

```
foo.stage.someRootLevelObject.htmlText = "Pretty <b>easy</b>";
```

Comment: okay, but how do I use a string instead of hardcoding the objectname?

Comment: var objectName = 'someString';
var object = foo.stage[objectName];